# Modify string soap+xml before send httpurlconnection - JAVA

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a soap+xml file which use to send in HttpUrlConnection body. I need to edit some value before send the POST like below

sopaXML.xml :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:int="http://service.com/integration/">
   <soap:Header>
      <int:Options>
         <int:UpdateLastModified>true</int:UpdateLastModified>
      </int:Options>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <int:Execute>
         <int:commandRequest xsi:type="int:TaskCreateCommand" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <int:TaskOrder>
               <int:TypeCategory>Request</int:TypeCategory>
               <int:Customer>
                  <int:Id>83</int:Id>
               </int:Customer>
               <int:Items>
                  <int:WoItem>
                     <int:Task>
                        <int:Id>16519</int:Id>
                     </int:Task>
                     <int:Comment>New Task 1</int:Comment>
                  </int:WoItem>
               </int:Items>
            </int:TaskOrder>
         </int:commandRequest>
      </int:Execute>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Need to change the value :

```
<int:TaskOrder>
        <int:TypeCategory>Request</int:TypeCategory>
                   <int:Customer>
                      <int:Id>102</int:Id>
                   </int:Customer>
                   <int:Items>
                      <int:WoItem>
                         <int:Task>
                            <int:Id>20034</int:Id>
                         </int:Task>
                         <int:Comment>Modified New Task Here!</int:Comment>
                      </int:WoItem>
                 </int:Items>
      </int:TaskOrder>
```

Code I have tried :

```
String url = "http://url/wsdk/Service.asmx";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/soap+xml");
con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "SessionId=0t10; path=/; HttpOnly");
con.setDoOutput(true)
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
XML xml = new XMLDocument(new File("src/main/resources/soapXML.xml"));
String xmlString = xml.toString(); 
System.out.println(xmlString);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());
SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage(null, stream);
// How to modify the values
String modifiedxmlString = // modidfied soapXML string
wr.writeBytes(modifiedxmlString);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
```

How to changes the existing value from string of soap+xml and post that modified string in HttpURLconnection?

Answer (score 0):

try below given code.

Note: Its hint not a compiled code

You have `SOAPMessage` object by which you can get soap body

```
SOAPMessage sm = ----- 
SOAPBody body = sm.getSOAPBody();

private void updateNodeValue(List<String> nodeNamesWhichYouWantToUpdate, SOAPBody body) {
        for(String nodeName : nodeNamesWhichYouWantToUpdate){
            NodeList nodeList = body.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
            int length = nodeList.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               Node  node = (Node) nodeList.item(i);    
               node.setTextContent("updateNodeValue");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If I pass List<String> nodeNamesWhichYouWantToUpdate= Arrays.asList("Customer","WoItem"); then it gives nodeList 0

Comment: Finally Changed into List<String> nodeNamesWhichYouWantToUpdate= Arrays.asList("int:Customer","int:WoItem"); now Entered into node.setTextContent("updateNodeValue"); but does not update value.